# assigning values in biginteger array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

For some program I need an array which stores a Fibonacci sequence number up to the 100th term. Although I can calculate that using fib function and storing in array, I want to save time by storing it manually. How can i do this?

I was trying to do this like so:

```
BigInteger[] arr={259695496911122585,420196140727489673,
679891637638612258,1100087778366101931,1779979416004714189};
```

However, I get the error "Type mismatch; can not convert int to BigInteger".

Comment: What makes you think there's a literal format for `BigInteger`? You need to use something like `BigInteger.valueOf("259695496911122585")` etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet, that's a perfectly valid answer =)

Comment: @JonSkeet It is wrong. `BigInteger valueOf(long val) {}`. valueOf takes long.

Comment: @JonSkeet  it means there is no way i can save time , i need to calculate all the fib numbers ?

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly: Whoops, I thought it was overloaded. Nope, use the constructor instead: `new BigInteger("259695496911122585")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an BigInteger array and try to add primitive int types. You have to create BigInteger instances which can be part of your array:

```
BigInteger[] arr={BigInteger.valueOf(1),BigInteger.valueOf(259695496911122585L)};
```

Or if your values are bigger as a long value use the constructor with String argument:

```
BigInteger[] arr={new BigInteger("259695496911122585"),new BigInteger("420196140727489673")};
```

Comment: yes , you are right but i need to write new BigInteger("") for every entry.

Comment: Yes but this can easily done in an good editor with search/replace or block edit mode. Also you can add the values to an array in your code when calculating and use serialization to save it for a later program use or just print them in this java array format and copy/paste them.

Comment: really helpful, please elaborate , how to print in java array format.

Comment: Something plain and stupid like this where bia is your array with the calculated values: `System.out.print("BigInteger[] bia= {");
        for(BigInteger bi : bia ) {
          System.out.print("new BigInteger(\""+ bi + "\"),");  
        }
        System.out.println("};");
     }` The String from this program can then be copied and pasted and replace bia in the java code. Comments are kinda limited to what I can type :).

Answer (score 1):

int is a primitive type, while BigInteger is a class type.

For your case, you have an Array of BigIntegers. So each element of the array must be of the BigInteger class type. You are giving it int, a primitive type, so it will complain.

To solve this, each indice of the array should contain an object of the BigInteger type.

```
BigInteger[] bigIntegerArray = {new BigInteger(#),.....}
```

Where # is a number, and ... is additional indices.